# Startup problems, 13.10 and 13.04

Tags: startup

I've run several previous Ubuntu systems on the same Eee PC with no problem. Then switched to xfce for about a year, now am trying to switch back to see what's new in Ubuntu.

On 13.04 and also 13.10, I download on a Mac, and did get the correct md5, and did write and verify on a DVD-R sucessfully. Both disks start to boot, but neither completes successfully.

On 13.04, pressing a function key while the system is trying to run from the DVD shows a screen of error messages. There are lots of them. This is my first time here so I can't post a picture, but they include:
Could not create certificate
Chroot: Could not execute 'Install': Input/output error  [3 times -- then further down on the screen, 3 times again]

and the same error 6 times with dpkg (instead of Install).

Should I order the DVDs with Ubuntu installed -- or is the problem probably elsewhere?

John

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you used the same Mac to burn the ISO to the DVD, there's presumably no problem with the DVD drive.

Can you run Ubuntu LiveCD?

If not, the I/O error sounds like it may indicate a problem with the DVD.  I had problems installing 13.04 on a Mac using a few-years-old DVD-RW.  Went to the store and got a different brand of DVD; that solved the problem.  Also check that the speed at which you're burning the disk is compatible.  Heck, even if you can run LiveCD, it may be that there are bad sectors on the disk that prevent full installation.  The DVDs are made differently and some (generally the more expensive, of course) are more compatible with the ISO and your Mac than are others.

If it's not the DVD then what I've seen on the forums indicates a possible RAM error.  You might check the forums as there are some questions on I/O errors and RAM.  Here's hoping it's just a faulty/cheap DVD.

Comment: Thanks -- I cannot run the LiveCD. My blank DVDs were old, so I'll try some new ones.

Comment: For the record, the DVDs I had problems with were probably 5 or more years old and have a brand name starting with Memo and ending in Rex.  As mentioned I bought some new ones of what the all-knowing Internet tells me are higher quality, and LiveCD worked.